# Is it possible to program a WebApp where u can import an .csv and export as pdf?

Tags: csv, pdf, web-applications, pdf-generation, adobe-indesign

So i am currently working on a project for my company. The target is to make an automated pdf genarator for our products. I want to programm an WebApp for this and constantly implement new functions. We have a prepared Indesign file with a guidline that needs to be met. My question is, is this even possible, to feed the programm with the .csv file and at the end i will receive a finished .pdf(with the design guidline).

It is my first time on StackOverflow, so please excuse if i was not precise enough :)

PS: I know about the Data-Merge function in Indesign, yet this doesn't work for us.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, however when you use it in an actual publicly accessible web app (as opposed to an in-house tool that you use manually), then you will need an InDesign server license for that.

But technically, it is definitively possible to write a script to read .csv files to generate a certain layout with certain contents.

Comment: Thank you, i was not aware of the Indesign Server, this has helped me allot. Thanks again!